# Смещение блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужна помощь, проблема получается в чём, добавил болок с картинкой на страницу , а все товары слетели в право.

[image: Как сместились товары]

Как их вернуть обратно, но при этом что бы блок с права остался на своём месте?

Код:

```css
/*Feature Glass*/

.reclam{
    float: right;

}

/*Товары*/

.midl-col{
    width: 757px;
    margin-left: 191px;
    margin-right: 452px;
    float: left;
}

.products-list>li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 28px 27px 0;
    min-height: 319px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.products-list>li:hover,
.products-list>li.active
{
    border: 1px solid #64608f;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(img/Korzinka.png) no-repeat 160px 247px;
}



.products-list>li:nth-child(3n){
margin-right: 0;
}

.products{
    padding-left: 13px;
}

.old-price{
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #464148;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.price{
    position: absolute;
    color: #7db122;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
/*New icon*/
.special{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.special .bue{
         background: url(img/NEW%20icon.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
}

.new {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 85px;
  left: 610px;
    top: 749px;
}
```

```html
<div class="reclam">
 <h2>Featured</h2>
 <h2>Glass</h2>
 <img src="img/Featured%20Glass.png" alt="">
</div>       

<div class="midl-col">
    <ul class="products-list">
        <li class="active">
            <img src="img/prod1.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                <p class="price">$388.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
           <img src="img/new.png" alt="" class="new">
            <img src="img/prod2.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="special">
            <li class="bue">yjasfasfsafasf</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="old-price">$460</p>
                    <p class="price">$300.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/prod3.png" alt="">
            <div class="products">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>
                <p></p>
                <div class="price-block">
                    <p class="price">$90.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: по предоставленной верстке непонятно что к чему относится

Comment: @DogeDev Чего именно не хватает?

Comment: У Вас всего 4 тега в html. Не ясно к чему какой класс относится в стилях. Хотелось бы увидеть верстку максимально близкую к оригиналу.

Comment: @DogeDev вроде бы изменил

Answer (score 1):

> ... а все товары слетели в право.

Они вроде как не вправо слетели, а вниз ушли.

Вы занимаете блоком с очками всю свободную ширину на стандартных разрешениях мониторов. 757+191+452 это 1490 пикселей. Рекламному блоку туда просто не втиснуться.

```css
.midl-col{
    width: 757px;
    margin-left: 191px;
    margin-right: 452px;
    float: left;
}
```

Попробуйте сделать так, например.

```css
.midl-col{
    width: 757px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Лучше чем было теперь они выровнялись как и были, НО теперь они прижаты к левому краю полностью

Comment: Ухххху я решил проблему таким вот образом .midl-col{
    width: 757px;
    margin-left: 191px;
    float: left;
}